# Syntax checking command in Ruby doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby. I'm trying to get automatic syntax checking but I can't even get manual syntax checking to work with `ruby -c`. When I run it on the following file it reports `Syntax OK`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

kjsadkf kjasdkfj ;j
lkjasdfl;kj
;lkjsadf

my r =



dig
```

Is there some Ruby config setting I'm missing? I'm on a Mac, High Sierra, with Ruby installed with Homebrew, I believe, version 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029).

Comment: Your Ruby "script" follows the syntactic rules of Ruby and this is all the interpreter can check without running it. If you don't believe me try to add some more garbage but this time use the symbols from the digit keys (`!@#$%^&*()` and similar). `ruby -c` will report a syntax error because of them.

Comment: Huh, ok. So how do I check for compile time errors like I do with my perl scripts inside of vim with the syntastic plugin?

Comment: If you have the opportunity, change to Neovim, install the Ale plugin, and you can use it together Rubocop.

Comment: Huh, never heard of Neovim. The future of vim, eh?

Comment: Your script is syntactically correct; there are no compile-time errors. It can even run if you [`require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require) it in another script that defines the symbols `kjsadkf`, `kjasdkfj` and the others.

Comment: Got rubocop working with ale. The async stuff is very nice.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the syntax highlighting of things with a different background color, however, it's very distracting. How do I fix that?

Comment: Ah, the syntax highlighting was just warning me to use single quotes instead of double.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? What do you mean by "I can't even get manual syntax checking to work with `ruby -c`." What does "I can't even get it to work" mean? Do you get an error message? If yes, what does it say? Also, you are saying "When I run it on the following file it reports `Syntax OK`:" To me, that seems to indicate that you *did* get manual syntax checking to work, after all, you got a response back from the syntax checker that your syntax is OK.